# exclamations mark shown with wifi networks

Tags: 2.2-froyo

I have an issue with my moto g 2nd gen ,that it's shows a mark like exclamation sign with WiFi network and work slow due to this sign .plz give me solutions for this problem

Comment: I don't think Moto G 2nd gen comes with Android 2.2 which you have used as a tag. Consider an [edit] if it's a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

The exclamation mark on the Wifi sign means that you are connected to the access point but don't have internet connectivity. Ever since Android 5.0, when this happens, it falls back to your mobile data connection. This is probably why the network slows down to a crawl.